# Extension Grants - Invalid Grant Type Delegation - Identity Server 4 .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to figure out how to implement a `delegation` grant type in conjunction  with `client credentials`, by following the tutorial from [HERE](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html), which is literally one page, since I have and API1 resource calling another API2 resource.

I've implemented the `IExtensionGrantValidator` and copied the code from the docs using the class name they provided, and added the `client` with grant type `delegation`.  However, I am not sure where and how to call this method below, at first I was calling it from the `client` and tried passing the JWT I initially got to call API1 to the `DelegateAsync` method but I kept getting a `bad request`

*In API 1 you can now construct the HTTP payload yourself, or use the IdentityModel helper library:*

```
    public async Task<TokenResponse> DelegateAsync(string userToken)
    {
        var payload = new
        {
            token = userToken
        };

        // create token client
        var client = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "api1.client", "secret");

        // send custom grant to token endpoint, return response
        return await client.RequestCustomGrantAsync("delegation", "api2", payload);
    }
```

So, I tried from API1 requesting a token in a method called `GetAPI2Response` which attempts to call a method in API2:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getapi2response")]
        public async Task<string> GetApi2Response()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
            {
                Address = "http://localhost:5005/connect/token",
                GrantType = "delegation",
                ClientId = "api1_client",
                ClientSecret = "74c4148e-70f4-4fd9-b444-03002b177937",

                Parameters = { { "scope", "stateapi" } }
            });

            var apiClient = new HttpClient();
            apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

            var response = await apiClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:6050/api/values");

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return content;
            }
            return "failed";
        }
```

However, this returns when debugging an `invalid grant type`.  Strangely, I noticed when running IDSRV the code in the `IExtensionGrantValidator` method does not get hit, until you click the link for the `discovery docs` then it appears as a `grant type`

I'm obviously doing something wrong since I am not including the aforementioned `DelegateAsync` method from the docs, as its not clear to me where it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs seem to be a bit outdated. With the actual extension methods there must be something like:

```cs
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
{
    Address = "http://localhost:5005/connect/token",
    GrantType = "delegation",
    ClientId = "api1_client",
    ClientSecret = "74c4148e-70f4-4fd9-b444-03002b177937",
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{{ "token", userToken }, { "scope", "stateapi" } }
})
```

you already implemented it, but forgot to add the initial token. When you extract it from the `GetApi2Response()` it can become your `DelegateAsync`.

Then your client configuration in Identityserver has to contain the *delegation* GrantType for the *api1_client*. Also don't forget the registration:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer().AddExtensionGrantValidator<YourIExtensionGrantValidatorImpl>()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200741/discussion-on-answer-by-d-f-extension-grants-invalid-grant-type-delegation-i).

Comment: Hi d_f, from where are you getting userToken? I can't imagine how to get it.

Comment: @JoseL.Garcia that userToken is just the orginal access token, the request to the "api1" comes with. It is the second word in the `Authorization` header of the request (the first one is always `bearer`).

Comment: Sadly my chat with @d_f does not exist anymore but I remember getting the original access token from the `HttpContext` to use to call the 2nd api which was in our *moved to chat*